# Creating multiple heads in remote repository

Tags: mercurial

We are looking to move our team (~10 developers) from SVN to mercurial.  We are trying to figure out how to manage our workflow.  In particular, we are trying to see if creating remote heads is the right solution.

We currently have a very large repository with multiple, related projects.  They share a lot of code, but pieces of the project are deployed by different teams (3 teams) independent of other portions of the code-base.  So each team is working on concurrent large features.

The way we currently handles this in SVN are branches.  Team1 has a branch for Feature1, same deal for the other teams.  When Team1 finishes their change, it gets merged into the trunk and deployed out.  The other teams follow suite when their project is complete, merging of course.

So my initial thought are using Named Branches for these situations.  Team1 makes a Feature1 branch off of the default branch in Hg.  Now, here is the question. Should the team PUSH that branch, in it's current/half-state to the repository.  This will create a second head in the core repo.

My initial reaction was "NO!" as it seems like a bad idea.  Handling multiple heads on our repository just sounds awful, but there are some advantages...

First, the teams want to setup Continuous Integration to build this branch during their development cycle (months long).  This will only work if the CI can pull this branch from the repo.  This is something we do now with SVN, copy a CI build and change the branch.  Easy.

Second, it makes it easier for any team member to jump onto the branch and start working.  Without pushing to the core repo, they would have to receive a push from a developer on that team with the changeset information.  It is also possible to lose local commits to hardware failure.  The chances increase a lot if it's a branch by a single developer who has followed the "don't push until finished" approach.

And lastly is just for ease of use.  The developers can easily just commit and push on their branch at any time without consequence (as they do today, in their SVN branches).

Is there a better way to handle this scenario that I may be missing? I just want a veteran's opinion before moving forward with the strategy.

For bug fixes we like the general workflow of Mercurial, anonymous branches that only consist of 1-2 commits.  The simplicity is great for those cases.

By the way, I've read [this](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/), great article which seems to favor Named branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely thinking about this right, and it sounds like you're going down a good path.  I'm a branches as clones person, but named branches have come a long way.

Having a central-ish repo to which all named branches are pushed is convenient for control and backups.  Teams working on only branch X can easily create their own branch X only repo by doing `hg clone -r X central-ish repo`.

The best thing you can do to help the teams out is to let them do clones themselves somewhere that's sitting behind a `hgwebdir.cgi`  instance (as, presumably your central-ish repo will be).  You'll find not just teams, but sub-teams and pairs of teams will set up their own repos for mini-efforts you never new about.  They'll put them on the named branches that make sense to them and merge back into central as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your experiences with it!  I like the idea of keeping my mini-efforts out of the main repo using clones, but I don't know how hard/easy it would be to merge back into the main repo.  It also means having multiple working copies if I need to fix a bug in the default branch(something we are trying to avoid).  It seems like having a named branch may be uglier(stays in main repo, may never merge in), but more useful for that scenario. Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I would make the decision if these three projects should go into one repository by the coupling between these projects (and how many patches are interchanged within them). The more independent they are the less are the advantages of having them in one repo (backup and management aside). There are some different kind of setups:

- As you showed, one repository, with one branch for the shared code, and one branch for each project. When the projects itself are generated by forking the shared code base care must be taken when merging back to common (cherry-picking). When inside of each project-branch updates to the common-branch are generated as direct ancestors of the common-branch, and get merges into the project-branch, chances are good they can also be merged back into common. But if changes to common are developed on top of the project branch, merging back will require cherry-picking. I don't have experiences with such a setup, but I fear that the merges can get problematic.
- one repo for the shared code and one for each project, connected by symlinks or as subrepo. Here care must be taken to not step on each others feed. In my experience this kind of usage has the potential to grow into a very big PITA. OTOH you seem to have this setup already and your fellow developers can work with it.
- one repo for shared and one for each project, with the code from the shared one used as internal releases. I would go for this setup when there are not big regular changes on the shared code base.

All these situations can also be combined with customization-branches for each project within the common part. But I would try to minimize the number of currently active branches, since every new branch requires additional care of merges.

I'm sorry to not give a concrete answer, but "The right thing" (TM) depends to much on the local details.